# Joining an Active Directory domain using netdom

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a simple script to join an AD domain and rename the computer. When I execute these commands directly on the CLI, it works fine.

When I execute the same via batch file, I get an error saying

> *The network path was not found*

I am running as Administrator with full privileges. I have googled around microsoft forums but my case is unique because it works from the CLI and not from the batch file

```
netdom join %%computername%% /domain:OPSCODEDEMO.COM /userd:Administrator /passwordd:xxx
netdom renamecomputer %%computername%% /NewName:%hostname% /Force
```

The environment is Windows 2k8 R2 SP1 running on Ninefold Cloud (Xenserver).

Comment: Totally off-topic for a **programming-related** Q&A site - this belongs on [Serverfault.com](http://Serverfault.com) where sysadmins hang out ...

Answer (score 5):

I suspect your double percent signs are the culprit.

You can see how it's executing in your batch file by adding an `echo on` immediately before the first `netdom` and running the batch file from an elevated command prompt. I expect that you're going to see something like:

```
netdom join %THE_COMPUTER_NAME% /domain:OPSCODEDEMO.COM /userd:Administrator /passwordd:xxx
```

How you're getting it to work at all w/ the double percent signs, even just running those commands on the CLI "by hand", is baffling me.